# Is this a good drywall hole cutter?

Tags: drywall, saw

Has anyone used this:  [Stanley Drywall Hole Cutter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003VSO4A0)

[image]

There are no reviews for it and I can't seem to find any on the web. I like the fact that it has two saws, though since I've never used a cutter like this, I wouldn't have anything to compare it to.

Anyone recommend another cutter?

Comment: For 6 bucks, it's a handy tool if you have a lot of holes to cut. I want one now! But then, I love tools, especially quality ones that do unique jobs.  lolololol

Answer (score 5):

I've used the single wheel version of this before, and it works fine.

**Pros**:

- Simple design. Just like using a utility knife to score a line, you cut your circle out on both sides, and then punch out the hole.
- Perfectly round holes.

**Cons**:

- Slower. To make the cuts at the same place, you drill a small hole in the center and then align the cutout tool on that hole.
- Error prone. I'd worry that two cutting wheels would only make it more difficult (you have to line them up, so they're cutting the same location).

That said, if you're doing a lot of cutouts, mastering a rotary tool with a drywall bit will be a lot faster.

[image: drywall cutout tool]

And a keyhole saw will be a lot more versatile for occasional usage.

[image: keyhole saw]

And if you're making lots of identically sized holes, then a drill mounted hole saw makes a perfectly round hole each time without much effort.

[image: hole saw]

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the size of the hole and how much you want to spend. I found what looks to be an identical copy [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Marshalltown-Easy-Read-Drywall-Circle-Cutter-NEW-/251243690752?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3a7f4a7b00) and it appears the smallest size hole you can make with this tool is 4". Obviously it's going to be slower than a power-tool so you'll have to weigh in how many you are going to be making versus cost. You can buy a typical hole saw kit like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001OC1958) relatively cheap set, this particular one only goes to 5" but you could also buy individual ones of some larger sizes as well. I also found a power-tool version of the cutter you showed:

[image]

[Product link.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001PI8S6O) This one is significantly more expensive but will make larger and smaller circles, it will cut through more materials like most thin wood products, maxes out at 1" depth but has depth guide, and solves the dust issues.

Personally though, I expect to make dust and unless I have to make a large amount of these, I would buy the cheap one and find a way to attach a bit to the back of it so I can use a power drill.

Answer (score 0):

For cutouts in drywall I always use a saber saw. More flexible because I can cut any shape of hole I want. The round hole cutter you linked is a nice gimmick but not necessary if you already have a saber saw.

If you need to draw a circle on the drywall to use as a cut line you can -

- trace around a round object.
- use a compass.
- even use a pencil, string and a thumb tack.

A simple tool for most any home owner DIYer or carpenter is:

[image]

These work with an ordinary pencil and can be used effectively for drawing circles up about 8->10 inches in diameter. Look for General Tools model 843/1 at your hardware store.

Comment: I already have a saber saw which works well. My thought with this tool is that 1) I have a bunch of holes to cut and this would speed up the process. And 2) I want to make some circular 'California' patches and use a tool like this to score two concentric circles. Especially for the latter purpose, using a saw would make this nearly impossible I would think.

Answer (score 0):

I bought something similar a few years ago. I had about a dozen lights to install and thought it was cheap enough to be worth it. However, I ended up not using it after the first hole. The thing picked up a lot of drywall dust that went everywhere.

I found a string, 2 pencils, and my hand drywall cutter. I used the string and pencils to draw the hole, then just cut it out by hand (one pencil is stationary, anything that can keep your center point still will work fine). Much less mess and not very difficult.